# ISO to USB || Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: 10.10, boot, windows, usb, windows-7

Trying to get a Windows 7 ISO to be written to a bootable USB from my Ubuntu installation, but it seems all the USB creators are for writing other Linux distributions, and the ones for Windows can only be RUN in Windows. Catch 22, right? I'm debating setting up a VM to run the Windows usb creator, but would prefer not to have to install the accursed Not Operating System twice in one day.

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Comment: No, my optical drive ended up coming in the mail. Unfortunately, patience won again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)? It should work, you can use any iso, including Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if windows usb creator works with `wine`?